# sql query for count gentlemen married,unmarried & ladies married,unmarried where gender=Male and gender =female

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.5

I'm using PostgreSQL. I want to count:

1. gentlemen married and gentlemen unmarried `where gender='M'`
2. ladies married and ladies unmarried `where gender='F'`
3. Total married count and unmarried count.

I can only execute gentlemen married and gentlemen unmarried or ladies married and ladies unmarried `where gender=?` but, I couldn't execute the entire below query. so, can anyone please give me the corrections regarding this below code.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE
               WHEN married = 'M' THEN
                1
             END) AS gentlemen_married WHERE gender = 'M',
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN married = 'U' THEN
                1
             END) AS gentlemen_unmarried WHERE gender = 'M',
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN married = 'M' THEN
                1
             END) AS ladies_married WHERE gender = 'F',
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN married = 'U' THEN
                1
             END) AS ladies_unmarried WHERE gender = 'F',
       COUNT(*) AS married_COUNT WHERE married = 'M',
       COUNT(*) AS unmarried_COUNT WHERE married = 'U'
  FROM station
 WHERE group = 'abc';
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many ways and finally, this below code works for me:

```sql
SELECT Sum(CASE
             WHEN married = 'M'
                  AND gender = 'M' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS gentlemen_married,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN married = 'U'
                  AND gender = 'M' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS gentlemen_unmarried,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN married = 'M'
                  AND gender = 'F' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS ladies_married,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN married = 'U'
                  AND gender = 'F' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS ladies_unmarried,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN married = 'M' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS married_count,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN married = 'U' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS unmarried_count
FROM   station
WHERE  rrcode = 'abc';
```